# transaction : except or on e:exception?

Tags: delphi

What exactly is the difference (and what to use) between :

```
try
  UniTransaction1.Commit;
except
  UniTransaction1.Rollback;
end;
```

and :

```
try
  UniTransaction1.Commit;
except
  on E:exception do
    UniTransaction1.Rollback;
end;
```

Is not 'except' an exception already ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The former will catch all objects raised as exceptions, the latter only those that derive from the class `Exception`.

It is not very well known but Delphi does cater for raising exceptions that do not derive from `Exception`. That is you are perfectly at liberty to raise an exception with an object that does not derive from `Exception`. In practise, I have never encountered such things. You simply don't ever see code that raises anything that does not derive from `Exception`. To all intents and purpose this means that the two variants will behave identically.

Since you do not refer to the exception object, there seems little need for you to declare a variable which you never use. Which brings us to yet another option:

```
on Exception do
  ....
```

This will catch all the same exceptions as your second variant, but does not declare a variable which can reference the exception object.

Which one should you use? You can use any of them and have the same behaviour, assuming of course that you don't encounter exceptions that do not derive from `Exception`. Were it me I would opt for your first option. It is the most concise, and it simply says that you wish this code to happen in case of any exception.

Comment: if using 'on Exception' it's nice to add a message, such as Raise Exception.create('Database Transaction failed: '+e.message) or something of the sort, that way the user understands the failure...your answer would be great if it demonstrated this..

Comment: @john The question concerns catching rather than raising

Comment: I get that, but his example swallows the database transaction without any notification to the user.. very poor.

Comment: Irrespective of notifications, the author asked what's the difference, and the fact that the second form gives an object containing information on the exception is important. It should be in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second option allows you to use the Exception object to add behavior, such as logging the exception, displaying verbose information as to the cause of the exception etc.

In your case, you're rolling back a database transaction, and if you don't provide any information to your user that you're doing so, he/she may think the transaction completed successfully.  In this case, I would do something like:

```
try
  UniTransaction1.Commit;
except
  on E:exception do
  begin
    UniTransaction1.Rollback;
    Raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Re-raising exceptions may or may not be valid in particular circumstances.  What is always true however is that using an exception to report an error to the user is an abuse and mis-use of exceptions.  Apart from anything else, the user may never see your carefully worded message, if there is an outer exception handler which 'swallows' your exception or if the default exception handler has not been over-ridden.; the display of unhandled exception messages is only a default behaviour, and that can be changed.  **Bottom line:** *Exceptions are not intended to communicate errors to the user*.

Comment: Of course re-raising exceptions may not be valid for all circumstances,that's obvious, and I didn't suggest to do that for all cases.  I have no idea what other code is involved here, perhaps a simple message would do.

Comment: @Deltics If the place where the error occurs is not in a position to report an error, then how would you do it without exceptions. You believe in error codes?

Comment: @JohnEasley don't forget about the nested transaction support. Better to use Exception.RaiseOuterException to preserve the first exception than lose potentially valuable information by raising a completely new one.

Comment: @David - first, raising an exception does not "report an error", it merely signals that *an error has occurred*.  In this suggested case (and in my experience, in almost every case where exceptions are used improperly in this way), by replacing an exception that already communicates specifics of a problem with a generic, unidentifiable exception with nothing more than a message string, *hiding all the possibly pertinent details of the error in the process*.  Second, even if the message is useful, the error indication might **never** become a report to the user, for the reasons I explained.

Comment: @David - and finally, an exception **is** an error code, in as much as it is a mechanism for indicating an error condition.  Effective use of exceptions is no less subject to rigour than any other discipline in software dev.  Naively throwing a generic "Exception" with nothing more than a string message that you can only ever hope will end up displayed to the user ranks in the panoply of bad practice right up there with swallowing all exceptions.  It is of course *possible* to use exceptions as the basis for a robust mechanism to communicate errors to a user but this practice is not that.

Comment: @deltics That's not what you said in your comment. You said that using exceptions to report errors to the user is always an abuse. Your latest comments contradict that stance by saying that exceptions can be used for error reporting. The code in this answer is not for production but it's also not meant to be. I think we all know not to raise Exception. Leave aside the specifics of the code here, as your comment did, and let's look at the concepts. You say that exceptions should not be used as part of error reporting. Then you say they can. Which is it?

Comment: @deltics What I mean by error codes, BTW, as I suspect you know, are values returned from function calls that indicate the result of the function call. Think Win32 error handling, for instance. Exceptions are fundamentally different because the calling code chooses when to handle them. With error codes all participants must deal with errors at all levels.

Comment: You also say that the code here replaces a meaningful message with a generic one. It doesn't. It adds to the message with extra information. Not that it does it very well. But that is somewhat beside the point of your hyperbolic comment.

Comment: Your discussion of whether or not the message will be seen by the user again seems to miss the point. For sure that is the case. But so what. Exceptions are raised when code needs to indicate to higher levels that an error occurred and the request task could not be performed. It does so with an exception precisely when it does not k ow how to deal with the error. Then it is up to higher levels to deal with it. The code that raises need not be concerned by that.

Comment: @David - Even if you embellish the message, any and all *other* information about the exception is removed.  This information may be useful, if not critical, to some outer handler.  Its type at the very least is lost, along with any other properties that may be captured.  It also shifts the location at which the error "occurred" to where it is *detected* (with a **new** "error" then occurring at that location, which isn't in fact an error but a *response* to an error).  As Lachlan points out, if you must raise exceptions in response to exceptions, at least nest them, don't replace them.

Comment: @Deltics So your point is to reraise the original exception, perhaps embellished. I agree 100%. That wasn't clear from you first comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if I understand correctly, Deltics objection is that exceptions thown must be caught (or program terminated). He's saying you should not rely on the standard Delphi Exception handler, that instead of terminating the program abruptely, defaults to showing a message to the user and resuming application. Being a Delphi programmer from childhood and having used Qt for some simple applications I tried to mimic that standard exception handler I'm so used to, but there is no portable (different compiler and OSs) way to do so in C++ (or it's at least very non-standard, non-intuitive).

Comment: @GabrielF I think we all know that exceptions must be handled at some point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in Delphi, if you don't, the standard exception handler will display the exception message to the user and give control back to the message loop, resuming normal application flow. I have tons of unhandled exceptions in my applications that are meant to just communicate the user of some error. It works, and I only discovered it was bad practice when I started working with C++. Deltics' first comment seems to be talking about this kind of practice.

Comment: @GabrielF We all know this to be so. Deltics clarified his comments. Apparently he was talking about specifics of reraising according to his latest comment.

Comment: After you catch an exception, it is implicitly freed by the compiler (since, it has to be freed at some time). Re-raising it with just raise doesn't free the current exception object.

Comment: @user763539 it's up to the runtime when to free it.. there is nothing wrong with re-raising an exception here as the block doesn't take ownership of the exception object via AcquireExceptionObject..